I want to install python pack with pip but shows 'proxyerror'
I use python 3.9.
I print, pip install mysql-connector-python
When i want to install mysql-connector-python pack with pip, it doesn't work and shows me,  'proxyerror Can not connect to proxy'.
I unchecked 'use proxy' in setting but it still doesn't work.
And i looked at a lot of source but i couldn't find a solution.

You can check Environment Variables. Ensure that no proxy-related environment variables are set.
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset http_proxy
unset HTTPS_PROXY
unset https_proxy

